# Scraping with Selenium some executions scan a data, others do not

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am designing a Python code using the Selenium library to scrape hotel data available on the e-dreams platform. The aim of the code is to scrape some data such as the title and the current price, store them in lists and then create a dataset. The thing is that the code runs but in some of the executions the price data is stored correctly and other times it is not. This is identified by the last print. Any idea why this could be? It is possible that there are anti-scraping measures

```
import selenium
import requests
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opts=Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36")
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=opts)

link='https://hotels.edreams.com/searchresults.html?aid=350435&checkin=2022-11-30&checkout=2022-12-01&ctoken=JfaDoWzscPcWaAMp8gw419frpsZ1zq0hhSN70OhXDJn3rXElJMlalObVxI1Y8fIJ2USoEpG_paizTh6YXrsxIRE3Vd8VdsRuWcL1BjSLkEWEGCS9n_miFb3LqswF5npXnOo2kWB_BcwuzzFUqUDsGIVUkQqBp5I3uQHxjE2ixEreVopkod_PsP7q1AXBD02SDe3zGSBdgKCpmWS1g2aiVThU6mWfLql3URPKRhweuZPevAra2DVMGnPcwrzLhlfPY6lE1uoLQWgOkZrdiu64IkegbctyGWuZzd3JpoBIZHWr2oti7CZOyDYUPnknJcG0bDC6OjSFQ6J1ZW6on3BjILPK9Wq0E_JKqrMs4IH0IRF96Txf4E_MtWNi34JLK5n5fQlqcc5UynwtQszkNFF0W7t6GKTvtAfQfW1Srwj3Rn8894DbBLnbtDfOOgs&dest_id=-2601889&dest_type=city&fp_referrer_aid=308918&group_adults=1&group_children=0&label=edr-link-com-sb-conf-pc-of&lang=en-gb&no_rooms=1&selected_currency=EUR&si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi&sp_plprd=UmFuZG9tSVYkc2RlIyh9YVXcKaaJl1ClKWK-8iYFdtMHKztuOGDCrZfdqiRGdeskuj-OEKqKFdayZs2UNKGuqQQHOdEClFirVT_0eoZ8amf7u6qjvNJ_hAHMLhfjuMoQH81__grdeE3tynZUX-P9WQ&ss=London%2C%20Greater%20London%2C%20United%20Kingdom&submit=Search%20hotels&utm_campaign=%28organic%29&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google&utm_term=edreams&'


page=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
hotel_name=[]
price_now=[]


for i in page.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'d20f4628d0'}):    
         title=i.find("div",attrs={'fcab3ed991 a23c043802'})
         if title:
            hotel_name.append(title.text)
         else: hotel_name.append('')
         price=i.find("span",attrs={'class':'fcab3ed991 fbd1d3018c e729ed5ab6'})
         if price:
            price_now.append(price.text)
         else: price_now.append('')


df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':hotel_name,
                 'Price':price_now})


driver.quit()
```

Here you can see the class of the price

[Actual price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYs3O.png)

I have run the code several times without changing anything at all, in some cases the price is stored in the dataset, in others it is not. It does not happen with the rest of the variables, only with the price.

Comment: 1) Why are you using BeatifulSoup with Selenium? You can use driver.find_element() to find elements? 2) Don't you think that class names are looking strange..? May be server changing them in real time for protecting from guys like us. I met with this problem sometime. Advice: print len of lists which you are getting, try use xpath `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "your_pattern")`

Comment: Well, I checked by inspecting the web page and the class names are still the same as in the code. It should work always....

Comment: i can't find any span tag with `class="fcab3ed991 fbd1d3018c e729ed5ab6"` on page from url in your code. it's point to think

Comment: I know for a fact that it is, especially if you look at the price. I will edit the post so you can see it.

Comment: if i see different class names, you can see them too after 10 minutes or 1 day or 1 month or in another browser or whatever

Comment: Are you saying that you have another name for this class?

Comment: Yes I have different names how you can see. Our values of span’s class are not equal

Answer (score 0):

Try find div with prices first using xpath:

```
div = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="price-and-discounted-price"])
```

In this div contains spans with prices, find them:

```
spans = div.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'span')
```

How i see, if 2 spans, first is old

```
if len(spans) == 1:
    current_price = spans[0].text
elif len(spans) == 2:
    old_price = spans[1].text
    current_price = spans[0].text
```

I'm writing straight in browser, syntax mistakes may be

Look at div that i have on this page. You need to find it, than find spans inside it

```html
<div data-testid="price-and-discounted-price" class="ca5bcdc79a e702eddf3f xh-highlight" bis_skin_checked="1">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="a0c113411d e293a04099">RUB&nbsp;33,526</span>
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="fcab3ed991 bd73d13072">RUB&nbsp;20,116</span>
  <div class="e6e585da68" bis_skin_checked="1">Original price RUB&nbsp;33,526. Current price RUB&nbsp;20,116.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException error..

Comment: Maybe something is missing in the code as I have executed it, could you adapt it to mine please.

Comment: @StackoverflowStackoverflow See update. Now you have a way to find prices

Comment: @StackoverflowStackoverflow You sent me screenshot of one tag, what did you expect when i said that i have different page from this url?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't get it to work...

Comment: I thought you might have different names for the classes.

Comment: Yes I have different names how you can see